# How to send and use the V7R3 created program object in V7R2 version of iseries/AS400?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have tried using save file with target system version *PRV/V7R2M0 but save file not saving the objects which are created with V7R3. How can i still use the V7R3 object in V7R2.

Answer (score 3):

`SAVOBJ TGTRLS(V7R2M0)` is what you need.

However, the object has to be compatible with that prior release.

Using the `DSPxxx` commands, such as `DSPOBJD`, `DSPPGM` you can see what version the object was created on and/or for...

```
Module created on  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   V6R1M0 
Module created for . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   V6R1M0 

Creation date/time . . . . . . . . . :   11/27/12 
Source file date/time  . . . . . . . :   09/27/11 
System level . . . . . . . . . . . . :   V6R1M0
```

I seem to recall for some objects, it's shown as "earliest release supported" or something like that.

Trying to save incompatible objects to a prior release should result in an error message.

Newly created Program/service program objects have to be compiled with TGTRLS(*PRV) in order for the objects to be saved with TGTRLS(*PRV).

So for example
`CRTBNDRPG PGM(MYPGM) TGTRLS(*PRV)`